# Combining `mmap` and UVM features

Tags: memory-management, cuda, mmap, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

Is there a function that provides these feature simultaneously? I am looking for a function that allocated memory which has traits of both "memory-mapped" (like allocated with `mmap`) and UVM (accessible from both host and GPU devices). I see that `cudaHostAlloc` allocates a memory on the host memory that is accessible to the devices, but no apparent way to declare the allocated memory ranges as memory-mapped!

My question is this: is there an API function to allocate a memory with above-mentioned traits?

If the answer to the above question is "no", then, is there a set of API functions that I can call which leads to the same behavior?

For instance, at first, we use `cudaMallocManaged` to allocate a UVM-based memory then use a specific API (either POSIX or CUDA API) to declare the previously allocated memory as "memory-mapped" (just like `mmap`)? Or, vice vesa (allocate with `mmap` and then declare the range as UVM to the CUDA driver)?

Any **other** suggestions will also be appreciated!

---

**UPDATE on Dec. 13, 2018:**

Unfortunately, the suggestion provided by @tera seems to not be working as expected. When the code is executed on the device, it seems like the device is not able to see the memory on the host!

Below is the code that I am using with the compilation command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <assert.h>


__global__
void touchKernel(char *d, char init, int n) {
    int index =  blockIdx.x *blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(index >= n)
        return;
    d[index] = init;
}


void process_file(char* filename, int n) {
    if(n < 0) {
        printf("Error in n: %d\n", n);
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t filesize = n*sizeof(char);
    size_t pagesize = (size_t) sysconf (_SC_PAGESIZE);

    //Open file
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
    // assert(fd != -1);
    if(fd == -1) {
        perror("Open API");
        exit(1);
    }
    ftruncate(fd, filesize);

    //Execute mmap
    char* mmappedData = (char*) mmap(0, filesize, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_LOCKED, fd, 0);
    assert(mmappedData != MAP_FAILED);
    printf("mmappedData: %p\n", mmappedData);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        mmappedData[i] = 'z';

    if(cudaSuccess != cudaHostRegister(mmappedData, filesize, cudaHostRegisterDefault)) {
        printf("Unable to register with CUDA!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int vec = 256;
    int gang = (n) / vec + 1;
    printf("gang: %d - vec: %d\n", gang, vec);
    touchKernel<<<gang, vec>>>((char*) mmappedData, 'a', n);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Cleanup
    int rc = munmap(mmappedData, filesize);
    assert(rc == 0);


    close(fd);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    process_file("buffer.obj", 10);

    return 0;
}
```

And to compile, here it is:

`nvcc -g -O0 f1.cu && cuda-memcheck ./a.out`

The `cuda-memcheck` will generate some outputs concerning user that the threads could not reach the memory addresses similar to below output:

```
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 1
=========     at 0x000000b0 in touchKernel(char*, char, int)
=========     by thread (2,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7fdc8e137002 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:touchKernel(char*, char, int) (touchKernel(char*, char, int) : 0xb0)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2cd) [0x24d9dd]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x22b22]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x22d17]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x570d5]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6db8]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6c76]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6cc3]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6a4c]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6ade]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x673a]
=========
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 1
=========     at 0x000000b0 in touchKernel(char*, char, int)
=========     by thread (1,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7fdc8e137001 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:touchKernel(char*, char, int) (touchKernel(char*, char, int) : 0xb0)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2cd) [0x24d9dd]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x22b22]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x22d17]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x570d5]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6db8]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6c76]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6cc3]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6a4c]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6ade]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x673a]
=========
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 1
=========     at 0x000000b0 in touchKernel(char*, char, int)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x7fdc8e137000 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:touchKernel(char*, char, int) (touchKernel(char*, char, int) : 0xb0)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2cd) [0x24d9dd]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x22b22]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x22d17]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x570d5]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6db8]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6c76]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6cc3]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6a4c]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6ade]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x673a]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 4) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x351c13]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x40a16]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6a51]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x6ade]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:./a.out [0x673a]
=========
```

Above output means that the code was not successfully executed on the device.

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE on Dec. 14, 2018**

I changed the code to following:

```
__global__
void touchKernel(char *d, char init, int n) {
    int index =  blockIdx.x *blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(index >= n || index < 0)
        return;
    printf("index %d\n", index);
    d[index] = init + (index%20);
    printf("index %d - Done\n", index);
}
```

If above code is replace with the old one, one can see the output of both `printf` commands. If one checks the `buffer.obj` file, they can see that the file contains the correct output!

---

**UPDATE on Dec. 14, 2018**

Probably `cuda-memcheck` has some issues. It turns out that if the executable file is executed **without** `cuda-memcheck`, then the contents of `buffer.obj` is totally **correct**. However, if the executable is executed **with** `cuda-memcheck`, then the content of the output file (`buffer.obj`) is completely **incorrect**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidentally I have just replied to a [similar question](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044920/cudahostregister-returns-cudaerrorinvalidvalue/) on Nvidia's forum.

You can [`cudaHostRegister()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#page-locked-host-memory) mmapped memory if you pass the `MAP_LOCKED` flag to [`mmap()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

You may need to increase the limit for locked memory (`ulimit -m` in bash) when doing so.

**Update:**
It turns out the `MAP_LOCKED flag` to `mmap()` isn't even necessary. The documentation to [`cudaHostRegister()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#page-locked-host-memory) however lists a few other limitations:

- On systems without unified virtual addressing, the `cudaHostRegisterMapped` flag needs to be passed to `cudaHostRegister()` or the memory will not be mapped. Unless the device has a non-zero value for the [`cudaDevAttrCanUseHostPointerForRegisteredMem`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g49e2f8c2c0bd6fe264f2fc970912e5cd) attribute, this also means you need to query the device address for the mapped memory range via [`cudaHostGetDevicePointer()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc00502b44e5f1bdc0b424487ebb08db0).
- The CUDA context must have been created with the `cudaMapHost` flag in order for mapping to be possible. Since the context is created lazily by the runtime API, you would need to create the context yourself using the driver API before any invocation of the runtime API in order to be able to affect the flags the context is created with.

Comment: Thanks, @tera for your response. I have a question though. This will basically is the Zero-copy approach. It is not like the UVM approach that allows paging capabilities. It makes the allocation locked and not moved. Am I correct? It would have been great if there was a UVM-friendly approach. BTW, I am not "tajiknomi" on the forum :-)

Comment: Nvidia might add that capability to the driver in the future. For now, this is all we have.

Comment: Hey @tera, would you please look at the updated content of my question?

Comment: Works fine for me on CUDA 10.0 - `========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
mmappedData: 0x7fbceeb88000
gang: 1 - vec: 256
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors`. You might need a newer driver or CUDA version - I got internal errors on CUDA 8.0 and 9.0.

Comment: BTW, you may want to compile your code with the `-G` flag to `nvcc` for somewhat nicer `cuda-memcheck` output.

Comment: I tested on CUDA 10.0, driver 410.72 and 410.79, Tesla P100, CentOS7.  I get the `cuda-memcheck` errors.

Comment: Interesting. I tested on CUDA 10.0, driver 410.72, Tesla P100, Ubuntu 16.04.5 (kernel 4.15).

Comment: The system that I tested my code on is an Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel 4.15) with the latest CUDA (10.x) and the latest driver (410.x) - just installed my system from scratch. My system also has two newly-released Geforce GTX 2080.

Comment: I've also successfully run your code on an RTX 2080Ti. CUDA 10.0, driver 410.73, Ubuntu 16.04.5 (kernel 4.15).

Comment: Just to update on my case. I tried to update the driver to the latest version (410.78) but my 18.04 Ubuntu was unable to see the devices. I also reinstalled the CUDA toolkit, but still the same problem. So, I had to revert to 410.48 and then install the CUDA . So, in short, I still see the errors when I use `cuda-memcheck` command.

Comment: My last update in case you want to know: I think `cuda-memcheck` was the source of the problem. I have updated the content of the question with my findings. When I run the program without `cuda-memcheck`, the output file is as I expected. But, with `cuda-memcheck`, the content is totally incorrect! You can check!